# Pegar tamanho do arquivo através OpenFileDialog e salvar em um List<Attachment>

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou fazendo uma aplicação **WindowsForms** para envio de email, dentro dessa aplicação tenho um OpenDialog que seleciono os arquivos e salvo dentro de um: `List<Attachment> AttachmentList = new List<System.Net.Mail.Attachment>();`

Conforme vou adicionando vai aparecendo no meu GridView, porém gostaria de exibir o tamanho dos anexos também.

Achei esse código que pega o tamanho do arquivo através do OpenFileDialog:

```
var length = new System.IO.FileInfo(theDialog.FileName).Length;
```

Como poderia colocar esse "dado" dentro do meu `List<Attachment>` e exibi-lo em meu grid?

Para exibição do meu grid: 
`gvAnexos.DataSource = AttachmentList;`

Comment: Windows Forms ?

Comment: Olá João, desculpe não ter colocado, isso mesmo WinForms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não possui nada direto, faça outra `classe` ou então utilize o exemplo abaixo:

*Coloque uma Lista de* [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();
```

*Adicione os itens do* [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    files.Add(new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName));
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = files.Select(c => new {
   c.Name,
   c.Length,
   c.FullName, 
   LengthDescription = fileInfoTam(c.Length)
}).ToList();
```

*No final você passa da lista* `List<FileInfo> files` *para* `List<Attachment> AttachmentList`:

```
foreach(var item in files)
{
    AttachmentList.Add(new Attachment(item.FullName));
}
```

Para transformar o tamanho de `long` em `Kb` ou `Mb` coloque esse método ou em uma classe ou no próprio código do form:

```
public string fileInfoTam(long length)
{
    double value = (length / 1024);
    string label = "Kb";
    if ((length / 1024) > 1024)
    {
        value = ((length / 1024) / 1024);
        label = "Mb";
    }

    return string.Format("{0} {1}", Math.Round(value, 4), label);
}
```

*Referencia:* [código](https://www.webprogramacion.com/178/vbnet/metodo-para-obtener-el-tamano-de-un-fichero.aspx) *dada pelo usuário da pergunta*.

***Outra forma:***

*Crie essas duas classes no seu projeto:*

```
public class AttachmentAndFileInfo
{
    public Attachment Attachment { get; private set; }
    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; private set; }

    public AttachmentAndFileInfo(string fileName)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            throw new Exception("Inválid path");

        Attachment = new Attachment(fileName);
        FileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);                
    }
}

public class AttachmentAndFileInfoList: List<AttachmentAndFileInfo>
{
    public IList ToSelectList()
    {
        return this.Select(c => new
        {
            c.Attachment.Name,
            Path = c.FileInfo.FullName,
            Length = c.FileInfo.Length,
            LengthDescription = fileInfoTam(c.FileInfo.Length)
        })
        .ToList();
    }

    public IList<Attachment> AttachmentToList()
    {
        return this.Select(c => c.Attachment).ToList();
    }

    public IList<FileInfo> FileInfoToList()
    {
        return this.Select(c => c.FileInfo).ToList();
    }

    internal string fileInfoTam(long length)
    {
        double value = (length / 1024);
        string label = "Kb";
        if ((length / 1024) > 1024)
        {
            value = ((length / 1024) / 1024);
            label = "Mb";
        }
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", Math.Round(value, 2), label);
    }
}
```

*Agora crie no seu form duas variaveis:*

```
AttachmentAndFileInfoList attFileInfo = new AttachmentAndFileInfoList();
IList<Attachment> attachmentList;
```

*Adicionando os itens e mostrando na DataGridView*

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        attFileInfo.Add(new AttachmentAndFileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName));
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = attFileInfo.ToSelectList();
}
```

*Pegando a lista de Attachment pronta*

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    attachmentList = attFileInfo.AttachmentToList();
}
```

***Referencias:***

[Classe Attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.mail.attachment(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Classe OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Classe FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Perfeito João, só mais uma dúvida achei esse método para converter bytes para kb ou mb. Como poderia utilizar ele?https://www.webprogramacion.com/178/vbnet/metodo-para-obtener-el-tamano-de-un-fichero.aspx

Comment: Aguarde eu estou fazendo um outro exemplo e já coloco esse também 5 minutos

Comment: João, obrigado! Ficou perfeito!!!!